# String input was not in a correct format- C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

I'm updating and deleting these tables by stored procedure...
Update query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IssueUpdate]
     (@BookID int,
      @BookName nvarchar(50),
      @DateIssue datetime,
      @ReturnDate datetime,
      @PersonID int)
AS
      UPDATE tblIssue
      SET [BookID] = @BookID , 
          [BookName]   = @BookName,
          [DateIssue]  = @DateIssue,
          [ReturnDate] = @ReturnDate,
          [PersonID]   = @PersonID
      WHERE BookID = @BookID
```

Update query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Issuedelete]
AS
    DELETE FROM tblIssue
```

C# code to delete from tblIssue:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {
        string c = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LMS"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(c);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Issuedelete", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        storedproc();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

C# code to update tblIssue:

```
private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    try 
    {
        string c = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LMS"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(c);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IssueUpdate", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateIssue", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PersonID", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        storedproc();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SqlError" + ex);
    }
}
```

After compiling, I get an error.

**String input was not in a correct format**

I tried other ways by changing the parameters with OleDB and SqlDbType... But it's not deleting and updating records... And also having same problem when I'm updating and deleting into tblReturn... Please, help me??? :(

Comment: Where do you add values?  `cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int)` adds the parameter, but aren't you missing a `.Value = `?

Comment: where exactly do you get the error?

Comment: You should consider putting the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using` statements, that will make sure both are disposed even if an exception occurs.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I changed the code.. cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ComBox1BookID.Text; but not updating...

Comment: @amitdayama when I delete any row in Datagridview, I get an error string input wasn't in correct format...

Comment: And also not updating.... I don't know where is my mistake....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your update code, Like DonBoitnott mentioned, you need to give values as well:

```
private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    try 
    {
        string c = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LMS"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(c);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IssueUpdate", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "Enter Value here";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "Enter Value here";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateIssue", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "Enter Value here";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "Enter Value here";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PersonID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "Enter Value here";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        storedproc();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SqlError" + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ComBox1BookID.Text; I changed but not updating...

Comment: Use new SqlParamter()

Comment: Does the value of BookID or PersonID is greater than 2147483647 (outside the range of integer)?

Comment: @amitdayama no it isn't... n error is same as before after adding the values... cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ComBox1BookID.Text);

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that because you don`t add values as pointed out by amit dayama, the SqlDbType, will act up.

if you could try setting the value of @DateIssue and @ReturnDate to DateTime.Now,
and exclude the rest of the parameters for now. 
for the rest of the values: 
int wil always have a value (o), but DateTime can throw an exception. for varchar i don`t know exactly.

Comment: I just chnaged my code.                                                                                             cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ComBox1BookID.Text; to this n error is same as before....

Comment: aah I see your problem,  int.Parse(ComBox1BookID.Text); should fix your problem.

Comment: it was exactly as the exception pointed out you tried to add a value, *.Text to a parameter with value type int.

Comment: error is same as before after adding the values... cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ComBox1BookID.Text);

Comment: why did you use Convert.ToInt instread of int.Parse(yourvalue);?

Comment: No, prblem is same @Wigle... :(

Comment: My problem has been solved... thanks ton for your help... @Wigle :)

Comment: No problem, tip, take a look at Dapper .NET